# How to get all elements in a schema using Delphi with MsXML6?

Tags: delphi, msxml

I have the the following xsd :

```
<xs:schema xmlns="urn:bookroom-schema" targetNamespace="urn:bookstore-schema"

xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="book" type="xs:string" />

  <xs:complexType name="booktype">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="author" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="price" type="xs:decimal" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>`

  <xs:element name="publisher" type="xs:string" />
</xs:schema>
```

This is the program.

```
procedure TForm1.AllElementsinSchema;

var oSchemaCache : XMLSchemaCache60;
    oSchema : ISchema;
    nsTarget: widestring;
    kk : integer;

begin
    oSchemaCache := coXMLSchemaCache60.Create;
    nsTarget := 'urn:bookstore-schema';
    oSchemaCache.add(nsTarget,'c:\book.xsd');
    oSchema := oSchemaCache.getSchema(nsTarget);

    for kk := 0 to pred(oSchema.elements.length) do
       showmessage('elements[' + inttostr(kk) + '] : ' + oschema.elements.item[kk].name);

end;
```

When I run the program I got :

```
book
publisher
```

How would I get this (all elements including sub-elements)?

```
book
author
title
price
publisher
```

Please guide me how to do it in Delphi. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You also have to write a loop for `oSchema.types` since `booktype` is obviously a type (or `complexType` to be exact) and not and element.